# The density of $(C[0,1],\|\cdot\|_p)$ in $(L^p[0,1], \|\cdot\|_p)$

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $1\leq p<\infty$. Consider space $C[0,1]$ equipped with the following norm
$$\|f\|=\left (\int_0^1 |f(x)|^pdx\right )^{1/p}.$$
Prove that $(C[0,1],\|\cdot\|)$ is an incomplete space by using the Open Mapping Principle (without constructing divergent Cauchy sequence) and this space is dense in $$L^p[0,1]=\{f: [0,1] \to \mathbb{R}: \ \int_0^1|f(x)|^pdx<+\infty\},$$ with the above norm.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. For the first part, assume that the space is complete. It is also complete for the supremum norm $\lVert f\rVert_\infty:=\sup_{t\in [0,1]}|f(t)|$ and for any $f\in C[0,1]$, $\lVert f\rVert \leqslant \lVert f\rVert_\infty$. The open mapping theorem says that the reverse inequality (up to a constant which doesn't depend on $f$) holds. Why is it a contradiction?
2. We have to show that if $f\in \mathbb L^p$ and $\varepsilon\gt0$, there is $g\in C[0,1]$ such that $\lVert f-g\rVert\lt \varepsilon$. Consider the following cases:

   - $g$ is the characteristic function of a closed subset $F$ of $[0,1]$: there is $(g_n)_n$, a sequence of continuous functions, such that for each $x\in [0,1]$, $g_n(x)\uparrow \chi_F(x)$;
   - $g$ is the characteristic function of a Borel subset of $[0,1]$;
   - $g$ is a linear combinations of characteristic functions of Borel sets;
   - the general case.

Comment: For the first. The norm $\|.\|_\infty$ is strictly stronger than $\|\|$ by constructing a sequence which converges in $\|.\|$ but not converges in $\|.\|_\infty$, for instant $f_n(x)=x^n$, $\|f_n\|=\left(\int_0^1 (x^{np}) dx\right)^p=\frac{1}{np+1} \to 0$ as $n\to \infty$. But $f_n(x)\to f(x)$ where $f(1)=1$ and $f([0,1))=0$ so this convergence not uniformly so $f_n$ does not converge in $C[0,1],\|.\|_\infty$.